# How to include Castle ActiveRecord assemblies with a C# project

Tags: c#, boost, visual-studio-2005, castle

I've run into what could be a potential problem with the professor getting a C# program to run. The documentation for Castle ActiveRecord says:

> If you are using Visual Studio .Net,
>   add references to the following
>   assemblies:
>
> - Castle.ActiveRecord.dll
> - Castle.Core.dll
> - Castle.Components.Validator.dll
> - Castle.DynamicProxy.dll
> - NHibernate.dll
> - Iesi.Collections.dll
> - log4net.dll

I figured out how to add references to Boost in standard C++ but my professor was not able to run the application because he did not have Boost installed.

Will the same thing happen with Castle? If so, how do I include the assemblies with the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a folder in your project to hold a private copy of these assemblies.  Then when you are adding references to them add a reference to the private copy rather than to the installed copies on your machine.

Comment: Basically link them in with a relative path?

Comment: Yes, but it is easier to add a reference and just browse to the assembly in Visual Studio.